# Correct way in CakePHP 1.3 to create zip file and download without leaving view

Tags: cakephp, download, zip, cakephp-1.3, render

I just upgraded from cakephp 1.1 to 1.3.  I have everything on the site updated and working great, except for creating and downloading zip files.

Here is the code in my accounts_controller.php:

```
  function zip() {
        $this->checkSession();
        $this->checkUpgradedAccount();
        $files = array();
        $this->layout="zip";

    /*
    code where I locate the files to zip, combine them, etc
    */

            $tmp_file = "/home/[userdirectory]/tmp/".md5(mktime()).".zip";  //directory name edited
            $command = "/usr/bin/zip -j $tmp_file ".implode(" ",$zip_files);
            exec($command);
            foreach($zip_files as $zf) {
                unlink($zf);
            }
            $file_path = $tmp_file;
            $this->set("path",$file_path);
            $this->render();
}
```

When I call this action, however, I get an error:

> Error: The requested address '/accounts/zip' was not found on this
>   server.

It worked just like this in version 1.1.  I'm assuming something has changed, but I'm not sure what, and was unable to find anything pertinent in the documentation.

The zip.ctp view file does exists, but it has nothing in it other than: `<?php ?>`

I suspect something is different with layouts.  There is NO "zip.ctp" in the /layouts directory.  However, I have changed that line to `$this->layout('default');`  and it renders a blank page with NO ERROR, but also with no download.

Please direct me on the proper way to download my zip file in cake 1.3.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different problems here.  That error you're getting is because you don't have a zip layout file.  As for your problem with getting the zip file, you should be using the media view class - http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html#media-views

Comment: Thanks, I wondered if there might be more than one. Thank you for the link. I missed that - it looks very helpful.  If I use my "default" layout, will this class keep my page from trying to go to /zip ?  I want it to stay on the same page and just download the file.

Comment: What layout you use shouldn't affect what happens with controller or model logic, assuming you didn't insert some unusual code in one of your layouts.  So I would think you could use either just fine.

Comment: Thank you - the media view seems to work great.  I can download pdf documents fine.  However, when I try to download a .zip file, the filesize is correct, but when I try to unzip it, Windows says it is empty.  If I download the exact same file by ftp (instead of browser), it's fine.  Any ideas?  I can post a new question if I need to.

Comment: My first guess would be that the zip files weren't created correctly.  Have you tried saving your zip files, then examining the saved files on your server to see if they actually have data?

Comment: I have.  I have even uploaded a valid zip by FTP, then tried to download it through the browser, and it downloads as invalid.  See my new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512990/cakephp-1-3-media-view-not-downloading-zip-file-correctly